# How can I make my select always use the current week?

Tags: mysql

Good day dear developers, I have a task to make my SELECT " always contain current weekly payment records", how can I do this, what I need to do with my duedate?

Thanks for your attention.

My select :

```
SELECT  duedate, interest_amount , completed_derived, 
       (principal_amount + interest_amount) AS weekly_payment_amount 
FROM `loan-schema`.m_loan_repayment_schedule
WHERE completed_derived = 0;
```

Output :

[image: output_image]

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please tag only the one database you are running.

Comment: @GMB, sorry, its MySQL. I delete oracle tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want records that belong to the current week only. For this, you need some kind of date arithmetics, whose actual implementatation depends on your database.

In MySQL:

```
select ...
from ...
where
    completed_derived = 0
    and duedate >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
    and duedtae <  current_date + interval (7 - weekday(current_date)) day
```

In Oracle:

```
    and duedate >= trunc(sysdate, 'iw') 
    and duedtae <  trunc(sysdate, 'iw')  + interval '7' day
```

Comment: Thank you very much!